# Can enemies perform "Critical Hits"?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I am not talking back Ripostes or Backstabs(The enemies I am fighting are [spoiler]Rats[/spoiler]. Under normal conditions they would take out around 1/15 of my health bar with a single hit, then seemingly at random they kill me in one hit, the animations of their attack aren't different.

**Not Bleed/Poison**

It tends to happen when I am mid-swing I've noticed.

Comment: Poison buildup would not insta-kill like that. Bleed would, but I dont think the rats cause bleeding damage. Are you sure you're not getting hit by more than one?

Comment: And even if they were critting, I have never seen a game let anything do 15x as much damage. Especially Dark Souls which is pretty good at being 'fair' (a.k.a. no surprises in battle).

Comment: My thoughts exactly, I am not sure what is going on here. The rats DO inflict two status effects but I don't know what the second one is, perhaps it is bleed. I am trying to tackle the Royal Vanguard now and encountering the issue every time.

Comment: It's definitely NOT Bleed, I can't even begin to explain this...

Comment: @Reafexus Daggers did 10x more critical then normal strike in the original DS, the closest I can think of. I wouldn't put it out of the picture, but I definitely do not think that is what is going on here.

Comment: I had this happen a LOT during the Royal Rat Vanguard - and it seemed to be related to the poison build up meter - an instant kill attack.

Comment: I haven't really had it happen to me outside of the Royal Rat Vanguard, I have been poisoned in the Gutters quite heavily and it only started the poison effect of draining my life. Perhaps it is a bug?

Comment: There is a "bigger" (he just has a spiky hair mane) rat during the Vanguard fight that is the actual boss. Perhaps he hits much harder than the regular rats.

Comment: @AdamP He does hit harder but not hard enough to one-shot me at full-health.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Absolutely*.

I have been both parried and crit shield bashed by the skeletons in Hunters Copse. I am unsure if these are the only enemies that will do this, but it is definitely possible.

It is to note that there is still the destinctive crit sound that plays every time this happens to me.

Also, there is a recovery period of every attack in which you will take increased damage. If you are mid swing when you are hit, this will add to the overall damage output of the enemies attack (regardless of weapon).

Comment: The last thing you said seems to make sense in the situation I was in. What an unfortunate mechanic as it's almost impossible not to get caught mid-swing in the rat encounters. I'll give it a bit more time before accepting your answer so other people have a chance.